# django virtual environment install brukva, Asynchronous Redis client that works within Tornado IO loop

Tags: python, django, redis, tornado

I am using tornado and redis in one of my project.
I want to install brukva to work redis with tornado.

But didn't found any particular guide to install burkva in ubuntu..

I have tried pip install brukva but it dont install the package..

Can anyone help me on how to install brukva?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily install brükva from GitHub:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/evilkost/brukva.git
```